# nomethoderror for devise gem (undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007ffa3e832cd8>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I don't know where I messed up

This is the error I got:
[image]

This is my routes.rb:

[image]

Comment: did you restart your server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and edit on your way:

```
devise_for :users, match: '', path: '',
controllers: {
  sessions: 'user/sessions',
  registrations: 'user/registrations',
  passwords: 'user/passwords',
  omniauth_callbacks: 'user/omniauth_callbacks'
},
path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'user/logout' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the server. This worked for me when I got this same exact error.

Comment: Please don't add answers as comments. if you like to remark something use the comment section.